# What is the Exit point of iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please any one can tell me what is the exit point of application?
I have developed an app, in this app I have passes an array in all views(used in whole application), an its running perfectly.
But I want to release this array when app exits.

Thanks.

Comment: do want the application terminating point????

Comment: @KingofHeaven: yes. I want to know when my array should be release as it is used in whole app?

Comment: the app terminating point is - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{}, you don't need to release anything when app exits. System will handle it.

Comment: But my array is in view so how I will pass it to appDelegate to release? Or you only tell me where this array should be release as it is used in whole app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}
```

this in your app delegate class.

Comment: But my array is in view so how I will pass it to appDelegate to release? Or you just tell me where this array should be release as it is used in whole app?

Comment: If its in your view then probably you release it in dealloc of the last view which is going to use it.

Comment: @Archana Chaurasia: You need to release the array in the `dealloc` of your view.

Comment: @PraveenS I did put a break point in this method but it doesn't come to the break point and I'm using iOS 8.1. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

In iOS with multitasking, you don't have a clear exit point. You application can be killed at any time without notice *if it is in the background*. So if you have settings to save, you need to do so in the app delegate methods `applicationWillTerminate:` (iOS without multitasking) and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` (iOS with multitasking). It's also a good idea to save on `applicationDidResignActive:`. See the [UIApplicationDelegate reference](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2Fuikit%2Freference%2FUIApplicationDelegate_Protocol%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=xqW_TZqRLYfQsgbzpoDDBQ&usg=AFQjCNFco4wGAzb5nDthm-Jp5cVDtXZFQg).

Note that all of these events also post NSNotifications to which you can subscribe to in any class you like. See the [notifications section in the UIApplication reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4).

As for releasing your array: you should release all your data in your classes' `dealloc` methods (yes, same applies for the app delegate).

Answer (score 0):

The `dealloc` in your App delegate should do it. Just add

```
   - (void)dealloc 
    {
    [yourArray release];
    }
```

in your app delegate....

Comment: But my array is in view so how I will pass it to appDelegate to release? Or you just tell me where this array should be release as it is used in whole app?

Comment: If you are using the same array in whole app make it an instance variable of your appDelegate and release in dealloc

Answer (score 0):

The array will be automatically released when the app exits, as the system reclaims all the app's memory. You don't need to worry about it.